# JQuery hover mouseenter event fired even though I left the div

Tags: jquery, hover

I have 2 div(s) as defined below:

```
<div id="feedsInfo"></div>  

<div id="feeds">
<ul>
<li><p id="a">A</p></li>
<li><p id="b">B</p></li>
<li><p id="c">C</p></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and I add hover event as follows :

```
$("#feeds p").filter(function(){  
 return ($(this).attr('id') == 'a' || 
                    $(this).attr('id') == 'b' || 
                    $(this).attr('id') == 'c' 
                )})  
.hover(function(e){  
$(this).css('background-color','red');  
 $('#feedsInfo').css('background-color','red');

      << dynamically append <a href> tags to div id='feedsInfo' >>

},function(e){  
$("#feedsInfo").children().remove();    
  $(this).css('background-color','blue');   
  $('#feedsInfo').css('background-color','blue');  
}):
```

The issue is that I can still see the link tags in div id='feedsInfo' if I just wave over the lists 'A' 'B' 'C'( The mouse sits somewhere else now.In short it should fire mouseleave event) even though they change color from red to blue and blue to red on mouseenter or mouseleave events.

Kindly explain how can I remove the link tags from div when I just skim through the list and mouse is not hovered over lists 'A' 'B' 'C'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#feedsInfo").html('');
```

Comment: No better luck. Still the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know which browser/version and which version of jQuery you are using.

Try `$("#feedsInfo").empty();` instead.

If that doesn't work, you might be experiencing a browser quirk specific to your situation. As a work-around, you could try putting a `hover` event handler on the parent container of the `p` tags, which would empty the `#feedsInfo` block. The mouse is normally going to enter the parent node once it leaves the `p` nodes, so that might work well in your case.

Comment: I use jQuery v 1.5.2 and browsers Mozilla 3.0.1 and IE 7. I tried plugging in hover events to parent container of p tags but with no luck still. Is some sort of event bubbling taking place ?

Comment: It could be an event bubbling issue, but it would be really hard to figure that out without live testing. Do you have a website where we could see this in action? Also, what does the code for "<< dynamically append <a href> tags to div id='feedsInfo' >>" look like? The answer might be in how you are inserting the anchor tags.

Comment: Here is the code for << dynamically append <a href> tags to div id='feedsInfo' >>
  $('<a/>',{href: entry.link,
    target: '_blank',
    text: entry.title    }).appendTo($('<li/>').appendTo($('#feedsInfo')));